# How to stop Rabbitmq Consumer after processing 10 messages?

Tags: rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I was running consumer from crontab and it processing all the messages one by one, Is there any way to consume only 10 or 20 messages and then stop to consumer.

So next time cron will call to consumer and same process will happen again.

Comment: @Vor's answer below is correct.  You may want to reconsider if rabbit is the right technology for you if this is your intended use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use synchronous `basic.get` method. Wrap it in a `for loop` or add sort of a counter. And quite the app once you reach desired number.

> This method provides a direct access to the messages in a queue using
>   a synchronous dialogue that is designed for specific types of
>   application where synchronous functionality is more important than
>   performance.

Comment: it works only for unacknowledged messages in queue what about ready messages or total messages in queue? how to get this count?

Comment: Im using code $this->count =  $channel->basic_get('queue',false);
it gives me message count =0 and queue contain messages in ready state